# Vim - Using Functions to Search (.vimrc)

Tags: vim, search, gvim, vimrc, macvim

I'm have a timing problem with a function that I use to search in Vim. I need the search to be executed immediately, not after the function ends.

I'm using "feedkeys" function `(eg. feedkeys("/pathern\<cr>")` to perform the search.

---

Here is a timeline!

```
          |                                            --> Need's "feedkeys("/pathern\<cr>")" result!|
          |                                            |                                             |
execution |call FUNC_A --> call FUNC_B --> return to FUNC_A                                          | execution
  begin   |                       |                                                                  |   end
          |                       --> Call "feedkeys("/pathern\<cr>")"!                              |    |
                                                                                                          --> "feedkeys("/pathern\<cr>")" search result!
```

Comment: feedkeys is executed after the function ends.  However I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please, avoid the XY problem and ask us about what you want to do rather than what you have tried.

Comment: Gentlemen, excuse my bad english! I improved my question above. Consider removing the negatives! Thank you!

Comment: You just made your question even harder to understand. Detailing your steps doesn't make your goal any clearer. Ask about your goal, not about your failed attempts.

Comment: romainl, see if became clearer. Please consider removing the negatives!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let @/ = "pattern"
```

is indeed the correct approach. You can influence the direction via the special `v:searchforward` variable. Go to the next match via `:normal! n`.

The problems with search highlighting are probably related to the execution within a function, see `:help function-search-undo`. You can still use a function to calculate the pattern, etc. but the modification of `@/` and `:set hlsearch` must be done outside of it, i.e. in the mapping or custom command.

Comment: Thanks again Ingo! I'm producing a script for Vim under BSD License ("Tree Clause License"). So when I finish this job I would like to present it to you and to the community! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solves the problem, don't forget to accept by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it!

Comment: I scored as a response. But, to solve the problem completely had to do a double search using "let @/ = l:pattern" and "feedkeys("/pathern\<cr>")".